# ReactJS | Map through nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following object coming from the BE. I load it through redux, onto a property inside my Component called `user`. This is the schema:

```
{
    user: 'root',
    perm: [
      "admin",
      "write",
      "read",
      "nodata"
    ],
    "auth": {
      "mode1": true,
      "mode2": true,
      "mode3": false
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is actually, map through the `auth` field, and for every mode, print in a `span` the name of each mode(THE KEY OF THE OBJECT).

So, I created a little renderSpan method to create the necessary boilerplate to map through:

```
  renderSpan = (authKey: string): JSX.Element => {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div key={authKey}>
        {user && user.auth && <span> {user.auth[securityKey]}</span>}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Then I mapped through it on my main render block:

```
  renderAuthModes = () => {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {user && user.auth && (
          <div className="container-fluid">
            {JSON.stringify(user.auth, null, 2)} // This prints the 3 modes
              <div>
                {Object.keys(user.auth).map(authKey => this.renderSpan(authKey))}
              </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
```

What I get in return, is 3 div with empty spans. The divs are rendered on to the DOM, but nothing is printed on the display. **What am I doing wrong?**

The Application is in React-Redux and Typescript.

Comment: You might have a scope issue since you're checking `user` in `renderSpan` while it is not an explicit argument. Depending on where your function is declared, `user` might be indeed `undefined` inside `renderSpan`. Hence giving you empty `div`s

Comment: But I have security checks. If `user` and if `user.auth`. How can it be undefined..

Comment: Stupid me. Sorry for the bother guys. I was rendering the boolean values and expecting to render strings. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

```
 {user.auth.[securityKey]}</span>}
```

Should be

```
 {user.auth[securityKey]}</span>}
```

Besides that everything works fine. The problem is that you are just rendering a `span` tag with a boolean inside, so the content will be empty... Try something like this:

```
<span> {user.auth[securityKey] ? 'true' :'false'}</span>
```

Comment: It is the same with it as well, my mistake it, leaving it there. I `console.log(user.auth[securityKey])`, and I get the boolean values, of those keys. I thought I should have gotten the keys themselves. I mean, I want the values as well, but not in the span.